# Is there a way to compile CUDA programs in a machine that does not have NVIDIA graphics card?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I want to learn CUDA, but I have a (late 2015) MAC book Pro with Intel Iris graphics card.

I was wondering what is the best way I can simulate/emulate to run cuda programs without buying NVIDIA cards. I came across GPU ocelet, but that seems to be outdated.

If the answer is no for the above question, is there a way I can at least compile CUDA programs (on some other machine) before running them on AWS?

Comment: You should be able to install CUDA toolkit without drivers, and thus, compile a CUDA app without any GPU

Comment: Write on laptop, compile(and run) on cloud instance.